# System changing display configuration on its own account - from dual monitor to mirror

Tags: 12.04, ati, multiple-monitors, display, fglrx

My machine is a 13" notebook connected to a 22" external monitor. Using AMD CC I set it up so that the notebook screen is my primary monitor and the 22" my secondary.

If I am planning to watch a movie or the like I sometimes switch my notebook screen off by rotating through the available display configurations <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>. That works fine but as soon as I restart my PC the dual monitor setup I configured disappears and in its place I get a mirrored setup. Rotating through the configuration option doesn't help.

As a result, each time I turn off either of the screens, I have to reconfigure the dual monitor setup on next system start. That wasn't the case before with Ubuntu Natty.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should create a script that replaces your `xorg.conf` file after every reboot.  Go into the `/etc/` directory, and do the following:

```
sudo cp ./xorg.conf ./xorg.conf_boot
sudo nano ./script.sh
```

This is the content of the script to enter in nano:

```
!#/bin/bash 
cp /etc/xorg.conf_boot /etc/xorg.conf
```

Then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit `nano` and then do the following:

```
sudo chmod +x ./script.sh
sudo mv ./script.sh /etc/init.d
update-rc.d script.sh defaults
```

I had to check out the way they do the `inittab` now, and I'm assuming that the thing edits the `xorg.conf`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'd rather find a way to set it up just like I did in natty without any need for additional tinkering but if there turns out to be no easier solution I'll be sure to try out your script.